# How to break the feedback loop and add the loading?

Tags: feedback, differential-amplifier, negative-feedback

I am trying to break the feedback loop of a fully differential amplifier and add the loading to the input and output:

[image: breaking the feedback loop]

I want to do this to take into account the loading of the feedback network on the amplifier's open-loop gain and bandwidth.

I saw some ways involving identifying the feedback type, which I find confusing and which can be viewed from muliple perspectives.

My ultimate goal is to find the value of Rx and Ry [see the picture] in terms of R1 and R2 without needing to identify the feedback type.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense (unclear) what you are trying to do so maybe you need to add a few more words so that it does make sense (becomes clear).

Answer (score 1):

The issue with analyzing feedback circuits in this manner is, as you have pointed out, how to handle the effect of the loading (there are other issues that I will briefly mention at the end). Using the technique you are trying to do, which is sometimes referred to as the two-port feedback analysis, is impossible without identifying the feedback type. The loading effects are dependent on identifying what the sense and return quantities are.

I like to view this feedback configuration as a voltage-current feedback, i.e. a voltage is sensed at the output and a current returned at the input/error signal node. The current feedback can be made more obvious by performing a Thevenin-to-Norton transformation on \$V_{in}\$ and \$R_1\$. For this type of feedback configuration, the loading effects are modeled by \$R_x=R_y=R_2\$ in the drawing you have posted.

For this example, with the amplifier gain as \$A\$, the open-loop gain becomes \$A_0 = -A\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$ and the loop gain is \$\beta A_0 = A\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}\$, so that the closed-loop response is \$H = \frac{A_0}{1+\beta A_0} = \frac{-A\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}}{1 +  A\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}} \$ which in the limit \$A\rightarrow\infty\$ becomes \$H=-\frac{R_2}{R_1}\$ as expected.

In general, this method of feedback analysis assumes the feed-forward amplifier is unilateral, and neglects any feedforward effects in the feedback network--- issues which do not arise for the ideal op-amp case here. A cleaner way to do feedback analysis is to use Bode's method, which does not rely on breaking the loop. Middlebrook's method is also worth looking at once you have seen Bode's method.

Comment: "Bode's method, which does not rely on breaking the loop." Without breaking the loop? Please, can you explain or give a short keyword? Don`t we need the loop gain function for stability analysis?